# Display picker and textfield like in address book phone and email entries

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uipicker

How can i display a picker and textfield on the same box, like it appears when you add a contact on the telephone and email fields.

Tried searching for a solution, but could not find anything.

Comment: Looks to me like a segmented control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manage that view by making customView. and set it`s frame above your pickerView. on editing text(if keyboard) and didselected(if picker) set text of that textfield.

this is exactly like adding toolbar on keyboard or pickerview...

hope u got idea...

Comment: Apologies for not accepting your answer for that long.